# InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "point" MongoEngine

Tags: django, mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

I am using below code to fetch nearest location from PointField using MongoEngine

```
restra = ResLocation.objects(point__near=[lat, lon], point__max_distance=distance)
        all_res = []
        for res in restra:
            all_res += [
                {
                    "res_name": res.res_name,
                    "res_address": res.res_address
                }

            ]
```

While I am getting below error 
**InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "point"**

How can I solve this please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem , it was a silly mistake from my side , posting here so that I can save someone else time

`point__near` replaced with `loc__near`  where loc is column name of the `PointField` in model class